# Is $\sum c_n z^n$ analytic when $c_n$ is Banach-valued?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, definition, analyticity

I'm trying to define "Analytic function".

I want a definition that covers all interesting cases.

To be specific, let me explain what exactly I want

Here is the definition of analytic function in wikipedia:

> Let $D$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
>
> If for every $x_0\in D, \exists$ a neighborhood $N$ of $x_0$ such that  $\forall x\in N\cap D, f(x)=\sum c_n (x-x_0)^n$ ($c_n$ is real), then $f$ is said to be **analytic** on $D$.

I **know** that every holomorphic function is analytic(in complex sense). However, I want to make the term "analytic" covers wider cases.

So here is a definition I figured out:

> Let $(V,\| \cdot \|)$ be a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}$.
>
> Let $D$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{K}$.
>
> Let $f:D\rightarrow V$ be a function.
>
> If for every $x_0\in D, \exists$ a neighborhood $N$ of $x_0$ such that  $\forall x\in N\cap D, f(x)=\sum c_n (x-x_0)^n$ ($c_n\in V$), then $f$ is said to be **analytic** on $D$.

However, I don't know whether this definition makes the term "analytic" fruitful. That is, if a function $f:D\rightarrow V$ is analytic in the above sense, then is $f$ infinitely differentiable?

If not, what would be a definition of analytic function that covers many interesting cases?

Comment: It's a little strange that your first definition of "analytic" is for real-valued functions. As far as convergent power series are concerned, the complex field is the natural setting. Real functions represented by a convergent series are usually called *real-analytic*, because unqualified *analytic* would refer  to   complex-valued functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the definition works and is fruitful (it helps with the study of the spectrum of an operator, since $\lambda\mapsto (\lambda I-T)^{-1}$ is analytic where defined). Note that  the real case can be reduced to the complex case by introducing the [complexification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification)  of $V$. Banach-space-valued analytic functions are well studied (Google search would bring up a bunch of sources). The notes [Holomorphic vector-valued functions](http://www.math.umn.edu/~Garrett/m/fun/Notes/09_vv_holo.pdf) by Paul Garrett contain a proof that a convergent power series with coefficients in a Banach  space is infinitely differentiable: see the very last corollary.

In fact,  the fundamentals of complex analysis carry over to Banach-space-valued setting so well  that one is led to ask: [Where does the theory of Banach space-valued holomorphic functions differ from the classical treatment?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95503/)

Comment: I feel really thankful.. Thank you very much !